# Your token has not been granted the required scopes to execute this query. The 'id' field requires one of the following scopes: ['read:packages'],

Tags: powershell, docker, github, permissions, windows-10

I am using Windows 10 Pro and trying to publish a docker image to GitHub by using PowerShell `tag` and `push` commands.

`docker tag 8a3e8abca3b6 docker.pkg.github.com/liufa/testdockerandk8/dockerandk8test:0.1`

`docker push docker.pkg.github.com/liufa/testdockerandk8/dockerandk8test:0.1`

However, I am getting the following error

> unauthorized: Your token has not been granted the required scopes to execute this query. The 'id' field requires one of the following scopes: ['read:packages'], but your token has only been granted the: [''] scopes.

[image]

**Where do I change token permissions?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
docker login -u USERNAME -p TOKEN docker.pkg.github.com

docker push docker.pkg.github.com/liufa/testdockerandk8/dockerandk8test:0.1
```

Here, replace **USERNAME** with your username and **TOKEN** with the personal access token generated with `read/write/delete:packages` enabled

https://github.com/settings/tokens
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself.

1. Go to your GitHub account -> Settings -> Developer Settings

Click new token

Then add the permissions that are required.

[image]

Then don't forget to scroll down and click  <kbd>Save</kbd>

2. Then go back to PowerShell and login again, but use the new token as password

Run the `push` command again (`docker push docker.pkg.github.com/liufa/testdockerandk8/dockerandk8test:0.1`)

[image]

Hope this saves you some time.